# Name of film with a little girl with an alien inside her body?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I want to know the name of a film with a little girl, (a child or perhaps 12 years old, tops) with an alien inside her body.

This little girl still acts like a normal girl her age, in other words she's alive and conscious, but every once in a while the alien inside her gets out and kills lots of people.

I still vividly remember a scene in which she's at the subway. The alien gets out of her body and kills everyone inside the subway. The camera is located from the outside of the subway so we can't see all the carnage.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? And can you tell us a bit more about the alien, like what it looked like and how large it was? Also, how did it get in and out of the girl?

Comment: intriguing, sort of like that russian scifi flick. is it YA or adult?

Comment: It sounds a bit like Species, but I don't think it's that.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the girl's name? What was the film budget like? Was it in black and white or colour? When did you see it? How gory/explicit was the "carnage"? What did the girl look like? Did she have any family? Where was it set? How did the alien get into her? How did you know it was an alien (e.g. as opposed to any other sort of monster)? What happened in the end? Did people know she had an alien in her?

Comment: This sounds somewhat like one of the opening scenes to "suicide squad" where the girl who hosts a god in her body loses control and the god destroys  a train & subway

Comment: I watched the film around the 2000's. The alien manifested with kind of yellowish octopus' arms. It was very large in a way that apparently infected the whole subway. It was shot in color. The girl was blonde. Apparently the army new she had an alien inside her. It might have been a monster